# In the usual sense of taking a limit as N → ∞, what is the probability that a random natural number is divisible by 5 or by 7, but not by both?

Tags: probability

I know the answer but am confused how after adding $\frac{1}{5}$ and $\frac{1}{7}$, you get have to subtract $2$ times $\frac{1}{35}$( divisible by both)?

Comment: What is the probability for choosing a general natural number?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur use the density of the sets.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the general probability rule (draw a Venn diagram!) $$P((A \setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A))=P(A \cup B)-P(A \cap B)= \\
(P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B))-P(A\cap B) = P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$$

where $A$ would be being divisible by 5, $B$ divisible by $7$ and $A \cap B$ by both, and because $\gcd(5,7)=1$ this means exactly being divisble by $35 = 5\times 7$. And 1 in 35 numbers is disivible by 35, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In every set of 35 consecutive natural numbers, you will find precisely five of them that are divisible by 7, and seven of them that are divisible by 5. That’s only 11 numbers, though, because one of them, the lone multiple of 35, is on both lists. The 11 consist of:

- 4 that are multiples of 7 but not 5.
- 6 that are multiples of 5 but not 7.
- 1 that is a multiple of both.

If the numbers we choose are just 1-35, then those sets look like

- $\{7,14,21,28\}$
- $\{5,10,15,20,25,30\}$
- $\{35\}$

Every other set of $35$ naturals will have corresponding lists. If you count all multiples of $7$, and also all multiples of $5$, then you can see that $35$ will be counted as both.